# Unable to unwind existing list of Documents within a Document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Initially I was trying to match by `fields.locations.id`, however this wasn't returning any results surprisingly. Browsing SO I've seen that prior matching an `$unwind` has to be done so it works (don't really know if this is still the rule in MongoDB >4.x).

Having the following document:

```
{
    "internalId": "idx8",
    "fields": {
        "city": "Winsconsin",
        "locations": [
            [{
                "id": "abc",
                "name": "A Bar",
                "tokens": ["A", "Bar"]
            }, {
                "id": "xyz",
                "name": "A Bus Station",
                "tokens": ["A", "Bus", "Station"]
            }]
        ],
        "extraInfo": {
            "randomMap": {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Performing the following aggregation:

```
db.sample_collection.aggregate([
   { $unwind: { path: "$fields.locations", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } }
])
```

This won't really do anything to the result and documents shown by the aggregation are exactly the same. Am I doing something wrong or have I shaped the documents the wrong way?

Comment: The sample document shows `locations` is an array whose first (and only) element is an array of objects.  Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct yes, multiple set of locations can be contained within `locations`. @Joe

Comment: This sounds like it might be an XY problem, what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: It's a complex structure ye @Joe, but this can't be unwinded before... It's weird but it's like that I know... The list of lists of maps is the issue mainly here right?

Comment: Since it is an array of arrays, the first $unwind will return documents containing arrays, and you will have to unwind again to get documents containing just maps.  An array would not help filtering after unwinding, so that query would have to unwind every array in every document each time, so depending on what you are actually trying to do, there may be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$unwind` will unwind exactly one level of an array - because your structure has a nested array you'd need this:

```
db.sample_collection.aggregate([
   { $unwind: { path: "$fields.locations", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }}, 
   { $unwind: { path: "$fields.locations", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }}
])
```

This will give you one document per item in all of the items in locations, so if `locations = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]` - you'd get 6 rows.

Answer (score 1):

$unwind open up the array in collection/query.

First of all, make your query look simple. no need to specify the path, as $unwind operator with a specific field name will auto-unwind it.

Example:

db.collection.aggregate( [ { $unwind: "$fields.location" } ] )
db.collection.aggregate( [ { $unwind: { path: "$fields.location" } } ] )

Both queries are correct.

As far as preserveNullAndEmptyArrays is concerned this option is used to include documents whose sizes field is null, missing, or an empty array.

db.sample_collection.aggregate([$unwind:"$fields.location"]) will work fine.